# How to return the argument of a mocked method?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

How can I make it so in PHPUnit a mocked method returns its passed argument?

E.g:

```
$redirector->expects( $this->once() )->method('gotoUrl')->will( $this->returnValue($argument) );
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the [PHPUnit manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest3.php):

```
$stub->expects($this->any())
     ->method('doSomething')
     ->will($this->returnArgument(0));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$redirector->expects($this->once())
           ->method('gotoUrl')
           ->will($this->returnCallback(function() {
                $args = func_get_args();
                return $args[0]; // or w/e
            ));
```