# Is there an equivalent to returnArgument in Mockery?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I'm looking for an equivalent to this:

```
$stub->expects($this->any())
     ->method('doSomething')
     ->will($this->returnArgument(0));
```

see: [How to return the argument of a mocked method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328622/how-to-return-the-argument-of-a-mocked-method/16367557#16367557)

Is there anything similar to this in Mockery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it using a closure

```
Mockery::mock('SomeClass')
    ->shouldReceive('doSomething')
    ->andReturnUsing(function($arg) {
        return $arg;
    })
    ->mock();
```